# Storing multiple values in one key mapping dynamically

Tags: solidity, blockchain, arrays, mapping

I am making a blockchain project using solidity which requires storing various objectIDs corresponding to a personId.
The person can add and remove objects and we cannot hard-code the number of objects. I am not being able to use the correct data structure for the same.
I have looked for 2d arrays and nested mappings but am unable to figure out.

Comment: What have you tried? Please share some code to better illustrate what you are trying to do.

Comment: You can use nested mappings.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can make a struct and then create a mapping with it.

Comment: If you have a concrete example that will make your point more clear.